# How to install cURL on Ubuntu 14.04 to run Craft CMS?

Tags: install, php

I'm in the process of installing Craft on my Ubuntu 14.04 server and ran into an issue.

When I run the installer at http://example.com/admin, I get the "Can't run Craft" error message:

```
Craft requires cURL in order to run
```

I have these packages installed using sudo apt-get install:

```
curl
libcurl3
libcurl3-dev
php5-curl
```

No clue what's going on. Could be a configuration issue? or are my packages not properly installed?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Derp... I was able to install it locally on a Ubuntu 14.04 vagrant instance. Must be something wrong with Ubuntu on my VPS.

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to go to /etc/php5 and either make a link or move curl.ini from the mods-available folder to mods-enabled. (Just did this myself on Ubuntu 14.04 server)

Also, be sure to restart apache:
    su apache2ctl restart

Comment: I looked in /etc/php5 and I don't see a mods-enabled folder? I do see curl.ini linked in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ and /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now. I had that same issue, and just went ahead and created a mods-enabled folder.

Answer (score 1):

I re-imaged my VPS and ran a new instance of Ubuntu 14.04. Now its all working.